# find region of convergence of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I tried to solve this question

**Find domains of convergence of the series**
$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{z^n}{n (\log n)^2 }$$

How can I do this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{z^n}{n (\log n)^2 }\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{z^{n+1}}{(n+1) (\log (n+1))^2 }\frac{n (\log n)^2 }{z^n}\right|<1\\
\implies |z|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{n (\log n)^2}{(n+1) (\log (n+1))^2 }\right|<1$$
See that [$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{n (\log n)^2}{(n+1) (\log (n+1))^2 }\right|\to1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit+at+n+to+infty+of+%7C%28n+%28Ln+n%29%5E2%29%2F%28%28n%2B1%29+%28Ln+%28n%2B1%29%29%5E2+%29%7C), and thus, the sum converges for
$$|z|<1\\
\implies z\in(-1,1)$$
Note however, that if $z=1$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{n (\log n)^2 }$$
Converges. Thus, the sum converges for
$$\boxed{x\in[-1,1]}$$

Comment: I do not know how this limit goes to 1 ??

Comment: @HamadaAl Use L'Hopital, for an explicit calculation. Else, logic and graphing calculators will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

For $z=1$ the [Bertrand series](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/series/bertrand/bertrand.html)
$$\sum_{n\ge2}\frac1{n(\log n)^2}$$
is convergent hence $R\ge1$ and if $|z|>1$ then the sequence $\left(\frac{|z|^n}{n(\log n)^2}\right)_n$ doesn't converge to $0$ the the given series is divergent and then $R\le1$ hence $R=1$. Moreover for $|z|=1$ the series is convergent then the domain of convergence is the closed unit disc.